# How to calculate PSNR of images of different sizes resulted from an image reconstruction process

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, resolution

Say if I have an image size of 250 x 250 and I've downscaled it by a factor of 3 using PIL library like this:

```
from PIL import Image
width, height = original_img.size
downscaled_img = original_img.resize((width // 3, height // 3), Image.BICUBIC)
print(downscaled_img.size) // should be 83 x 83 or something like that
```

So, now if I want to scale it back by a factor 3 I'd get an image size of 249 x 249, which is different from its orginal copy. In this case, I wonder how can I calculate the PSNR between these two images? Should I remove 1 pixel from all borders from the original image to make it 249 x 249 and then calculate PSNR?

Thanks a lot,

JZ

Comment: There's going to be an alignment issue. Why not resize it back to its original size?

Comment: @jodag I can't. I've got a function that upscale images with integer factors and I want to test it on standard benchmark datasets where most images are of even sizes.  Thus I'm wondering if there is a way to deal with the said case.

Comment: I see. You could use interpolation when sampling pixels from your image but then you're effectively scaling the image anyway (from 249 x 249 to 250 x 250). If you are set on using PSNR the only options I see are either scaling your image, scaling the target image (which probably shouldn't be done if you want a fair comparison with other methods), or padding your image with zeros (which is also a form of scaling). In the padded case, due to pixel alignment you will get larger errors the closer you get to the padded edges.

Comment: @jodag Thanks for your advice mate! I actuall think that maybe I can chop off a few pixels from the borders of the original image to make the size divisble by 3. Then it can be downscaled by 3 and then be upscaled back. This way I've dodged the bullet  and can also test my function.